Pyfirmata2 AttributeError: object has no attribute 'analog'
I'm having issues using pyfirmata2 (abridged script below):

Script:

import pyfirmata2

PORT = pyfirmata2.Arduino.AUTODETECT
board = pyfirmata2.Arduino(PORT)
print("Arduino connected")


Error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
    board = pyfirmata2.Arduino(PORT)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Arduino' object has no attribute 'analog'

I tried switching from python 3.12 to 3.11. I uninstalled and reinstalled everything. Still getting the same error. IDE script StandardFirmata has been uploaded. I wasn't getting this error last week. What gives? Thanks

It's a bug in pyFirmata2. Please report it but provide full traceback, not just the last few lines.
